# How to escape ® and ™ characters to its character and numeric entity like &reg; and &trade; in a query

Tags: oracle10g

For example, if the data in a column is

`Descp

---

Comprhensive review ® `

how to retrieve the data as

Comprhensive review &reg ;

or

Comprhensive review ® ;

Answer (score 0):

the replace function `replace(input_str, tm_str, '&trade')` can be nested. You'll need one call for each.

In Sqlplus you'll want to `set scan off`.